# Is there any special purpose of using each() in jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my code.. Instead of using .each() we can do just the same work by using the selector see my code below

```
$( "li" ).addClass( "foo" );
```

**so why to use this **

```
$( "li" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "foo" );
});
```

Comment: It depends on the complexity and the task you are working. What you do, if only certain elements that has attribute value=something then addClass? In this case use .each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example there is no point using `each` as `addClass` will work on all elements within a selector.

There are cases however where you need to get data for each specific element in a selector, which is why `each()` is used. Something like this:

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
    var bar = $(this).data('unique-information'); // this would be different on each .foo element
    $(this).plugin({
        some-setting: bar
    });
});
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman it's true. All I have for company are these value-less internet points ;)

Comment: Man even i dont have repo :P i need 15 repo to vote up .. :)
i am new here ..  @PatrickHofman :)
joined stackoverflow one month ago.. :P

Comment: Man even i dont have repo :P i need 15 repo to vote up .. :)
i am new here ..  @RoryMcCrossan:)
joined stackoverflow one month ago.. :P

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Now you have 10 extra ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `each` when you want to perform different actions for each element. The first case will apply common action on all the matching elements.

In your example, the first case is the correct way.

**Update:** Example on why you would need `each`. Consider the below `html`:

```
<ul>
    <li class="change-bg-and-add-p"></li>
    <li class="change-bg-and-add-div"></li>
    <li class="do-nothing"></li>
</ul>
```

What would you do if you have to change each `li` element based on the class? This is not possible with your first example. However, by using `each`, you could change each `li` as you are looping trough each matching element.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, *no* there is not added value for the `each` method.

If you want to do more calculations for each element you need the `each` method.

Consider this sample:

```
var i = 0;

$( "li" ).each(function() {
  if (i/2 == 0)
  {
      $( this ).addClass( "foo-even" );
  }
  else
  {
      $( this ).addClass( "foo-odd" );
  }

  i = i + 1;
});
```

Here you do need the `each` since you want to take different actions on each item depending on some calculation.

Comment: ohhhh that means each() acts as a loop which iterate through each li present or whatever the element is.. @patrick

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to do something more complicated:

```
$( "li" ).each(function() {
  klass = $(this).attr('data-class');
  $( this ).addClass( klass );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.each is meant to be used to apply a function to a set of html elements, where you may have different conditions for what to do to each element, while the first statement you proposed applies the same action to all elements of the name. In your example, the .each method is completely pointless as you can do it better using addClass on "li"

Comment: ok thanks now i got it..
that means when we want to iterate through various li's we need .each() .
every time we get different value by looping and we can do the work accordingly.. :) @benderman :)

Comment: That's correct. To do different actions to each li $.each() would be the correct function to use. But if you can apply a single function to all (like addClass) always do that to make it simpler.